# Get Cordinates on mouse click on google map api v3 and angularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
$scope.map = {
    center: {
        latitude: 36,
        longitude: -80
    },
    zoom: 3,
    showOverlay: true,
    events: {
        "click": function ()
        { console.log(" latitude: " + $scope.map.center.latitude + "longitude: " + $scope.map.center.longitude); }
    },
    options: {
        streetViewControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 1,

    }
}
```

So I have a problem to get the longitude and latitude of my mouse click event using angularJS and the google map api v3. Here is an example of my controller. I've added an event to the map so to get the cordinates, but now what i'm getting is just the cordinates of the  center. I don't have any idea how to get the exact cordinates of my mouse click event. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must implement a listener that catches the click and gets location:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    alert(event.latLng);  // in event.latLng  you have the coordinates of click
});
```

Check this [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LzezLgtz/9/)

Comment: That's working using Standard JS, but i'm using Controllers with AngularJS and it's not working like that, events are on my map but latLng is not defined and I think i can't get position like that.

Comment: If you cant use `javascript` delete the tag from your question... if not, define the map with `angularjs` and use `javascript` to implement listeners...

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I will try that and combine it with the github solution given by kiro112.

Answer (score 1):

The click event in Angular and google maps v3 returns three objects: instance, eventName, handler.

The third one has **latLong** with lat(), lng() functions.

So you can get latitude by handler[0].latLng.lat().

There is also a useful **pixel** object with position attributes x,y of the clicked point.

Comment: any reason for the down vote?
I've solved the exact problem asked with this solution.

Comment: This should be the real answer,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular why wont you use its directive for maps.
[ngMap](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)

Comment: There are many directives for google maps. He is using a different directive. ngMap is not the only one.

Comment: He is actually not using any directives.. He is just putting Map info on the controller $scope.

Comment: I am using [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/google-map) and I have the exact same setup in my controller. A directive is in the HTML the logic is in the controller. NgMap uses names functions connected to their directive.